# Verify the coefficient of $x^n$ from expansion is $\binom{2n+1}{n}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

So... after 20 years I decided to mess with math again... And I now I feel I am either completely off, or missing a more explicit explanation on this one, can anyone give me a hand?

Verify that the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\binom {2n+1} {n}$ from the expansion

$(1+x)^{2n} + x(1+x)^{2n-1} + x^2(1+x)^{2n-2} + ... + x^n(1+x)^{n}$

[EDITED: removed proposed solution kept in the bottom for future reference]

I have realized the misspelling, that actually came into my calculations as well... SO i removed my erroneous stuff...

Thank you!

[reference: error... me being an idiot]
From this I have used Newton's binom to reach the following:

$\sum^{2n}_{k=0}{\binom{2n}{k}}x^k(1+x)^{2n-k}$
which I transformed to, for $k=n$:

$\sum^{2n}_{k=n}{\binom{2n}{n}}x^n.(1+x)^{n} \iff$

$\sum^{2n}_{k=n}{\binom{2n}{n}}x^n.\sum^n_{j=0}\binom{n}{n}x^{n-j} \iff$

To me this means that each parcel is multiplied by the sequence $\brace {1,x^, x^2, ..., x^n} $

hence the combinations for the coefficient being $\binom{2n+1} {n}$

Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean $(1+x)^{2n} + x(1+x)^{2n-1} + x^2(1+x)^{2n-2} + \dots + x^n(1+x)^{n}$ ?

Comment: @robjohn you are a life saver, I mispelled that every time since I began looking at this... that probably confused me even more.
So I have just removed my erroneous stuff...

Comment: I sincerely aplogize for my mistakes and stupidity ! Answer deleted.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici if we were to apologize for that I would take the prize :-) thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Critique of the Attempt**

I don't understand how you got to
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}x^k(1+x)^{2n-k}
$$
because that is $(1+2x)^{2n}$ and the coefficient of $x^n$ in that is $2^n\binom{2n}{n}$.

Unless I am mistaken, the second transformation is just plain wrong. You've gone to each term and replaced the index variable, $k$, with the constant, $n$. Then you removed half the terms by starting the summation at $n$ instead of $0$.

---

**Answer to the Question Asked**

The question asked is
$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^n\right]\sum_{k=0}^nx^k(1+x)^{2n-k}
&=\left[x^n\right](1+x)^n\sum_{k=0}^nx^k(1+x)^{n-k}\tag1\\
&=\left[x^n\right](1+x)^n\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{(1+x)-x}\tag2\\[6pt]
&=\left[x^n\right]\left((1+x)^{2n+1}-(1+x)^nx^{n+1}\right)\tag3\\[9pt]
&=\color{#090}{\left[x^n\right](1+x)^{2n+1}}-\color{#C00}{\left[x^n\right](1+x)^nx^{n+1}}\tag4\\[3pt]
&=\color{#090}{\binom{2n+1}{n}}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: pulled a factor of $(1+x)^n$ out front
$(2)$: [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for the sum of a geometric series
$(3)$: note that the denominator of the fraction is $1$, then distribute $(1+x)^n$
$(4)$: the ["coefficient of" operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients) is real linear
$(5)$: apply the binomial theorem to the left term and note that the right term is a multiple of $x^{n+1}$

---

**Another Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^n\right]\sum_{k=0}^nx^k(1+x)^{2n-k}
&=\left[x^n\right]\sum_{k=0}^{2n}x^k(1+x)^{2n-k}\tag6\\
&=\left[x^n\right]\frac{(1+x)^{2n+1}-x^{2n+1}}{(1+x)-x}\tag7\\[9pt]
&=\color{#090}{\left[x^n\right](1+x)^{2n+1}}-\color{#C00}{\left[x^n\right]x^{2n+1}}\tag8\\[9pt]
&=\color{#090}{\binom{2n+1}{n}}\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(6)$: include terms that are multiples of $x^{n+1}$
$(7)$: formula for the sum of a geometric series
$(8)$: denominator is $1$ and the "coefficient of" operator is real linear
$(9)$: apply the binomial theorem to the left term and the right term is $0$

Comment: Shame on me ! Cheers :-(

Comment: @robjohn, yes, I was just completely off and wrong... I fully understood your approaches, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take.

For the moment, let $y=1+x$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{2n} + x(1+x)^{2n-1} + \cdots + x^n(1+x)^{n}
  & = y^{2n} + xy^{2n-1} + \cdots + x^n y^{n}
\\& = y^{n}(y^{n} + xy^{n-1} + \cdots + x^n )
\\& = y^{n}\frac{y^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{y-x}
\\& = y^{n}(y^{n+1}-x^{n+1})
\\& = y^{2n+1}-x^{n+1}y^{n}
\\& = (1+x)^{2n+1}-x^{n+1}(1+x)^{n}
\end{align}
$$
Clearly, $x^n$ appears only in expansion of the first term and so its coefficient is $\binom{2n+1}{n}$.